# Real-world example of a simple derivative application

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am learning some basic concepts of derivative, not because I have to, but because I enjoy Maths. Maybe, for not having to work directly with this type of calculation, I lack when it comes to real-world problems.

Could you please try to show me a real-world problem that uses derivative? 
I do know that we use the derivative to find out what is the slope of a function with a degree greater than 1

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: In physics velocity is the derivative of position

Comment: Acceleration is the second derivative of the position function or the first derivative of the velocity function.

Comment: Ok, guys, could you come up a with an example of this velocity problem as well as the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of physics, we have velocity and acceleration.

In terms of economics, derivative appears in elasticity and it helps you to understand the impact of adjusting the price on your revenue.

For a function that is differentiable, derivative help you to find the optimal value. Optimization is used widely in machine learning. For example, gradient descent based algorithm are used in learning the parameters of neural network to help you make good predictions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I do not see the real usability of it. For example: Let's suppose that I want to find out how the quantity produced affects the costs. Let's suppose that x is the quantity and y is the total cost, thus f(x) = x2 -10x + 5. If I want to see in each moment my costs overprice the product itself, wouldn't it be more reasoble to find out in each point in x my price is greater than my revenue? I dont know if I made myself clear, and I am sorry for my bad English, it turns out that I speak Portuguese as mother tongue

Comment: You haven't considered an important factor in setting up a business, the demand market. you want to know how does increasing a unit price affect the demand, whether the number of consumer will turn away from your product.  For a start, perhaps you might want to look at [newsvendor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsvendor_model) problem. You can see how derivative is used on the wiki page. Newsvendor model is a widely used model.

Comment: I see, thank you so much. Just for clarification: The real use of a derivative is to find the slope of a function on an exact point, right? And the slope of a function means how much Y increases or decreases according to X. Am I right or I lack in concepts?

Comment: yes, that is right.